# Are coalesce + orderBy commutative in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, palantir-foundry, commutativity

I want to run the following code:

```py
df = df.coalesce(1).orderBy(["my_col"])
```

but its execution will obviously bottleneck on a single task doing all the sort work.

I know it's possible to run the following:

```py
df = df.orderBy(["my_col"]).coalesce(1)
```

however I am uncertain if Spark will maintain the ordering after the partitions are collapsed.  Does it?

The second code will be preferred if so as the sort will be performed distributed and the results merged after, but I am worried it might not be properly preserved.

If it *is* preserved, this would mean the two are commutative!

Answer (score 3):

It's easy to know what Spark will do by using `explain`

```
> df = spark.range(1,100)
> df.coalesce(1).orderBy('id').explain()
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) Sort [id#0L ASC NULLS FIRST], true, 0
+- Coalesce 1
   +- *(1) Range (1, 100, step=1, splits=4)
```

So the answer is, they are not commutative.